# No module named 'roslib' when convert .bag to .mp4

Tags: ubuntu, ros, mp4, rosbag

I used Intel RealSense Depth Camera D435i to record some videos, exported them as a .bag file and try to convert them into .mp4.

I just found a GitHub repo that has done a similar thing called [rosbag2video](https://github.com/mlaiacker/rosbag2video).

However, when I installed the dependencies it required and run the script, I got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'roslib'`

I did try to follow the blog which is [Installing ROS2 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://rahulbhadani.medium.com/installing-ros2-on-ubuntu-22-04-4f1e89d7139d) with no error emerged.

When I run `python rosbag2video.py location1.bag`, it still contains the same problems.

My system info will be:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Release:        22.04

Codename:       jammy

=================== Update ===================

I discover one possible reason from [rospy/Troubleshooting](http://roswiki.autolabor.com.cn/rospy(2f)Troubleshooting.html).

> This probably means that your PYTHONPATH is not configured. Please make sure that your PYTHONPATH includes $ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src.

It should be done when i
`echo "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` and `source ~/.bashrc` according to the blog?

Since no error emerge when installing ROS2 according the blog above, the update section is for reference only.

Comment: Is this an error when trying to install the deps or when running the script?

Comment: @BTables this is an error when running the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roslib` is a module that contains ROS1 support packages and does not exist for ROS2. This is an error in the code on GitHub and you can fix it by simply removing line 14 of `rosbag2video.py`. You will also need to remove all other ROS1 dependencies included in that file as well.

Comment: rosbag2video.py can't be used anymore, since I have installed ROS2. If I remove  `roslib`, it will emerge another error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospy'`

Comment: @Vopsix `rospy` is the python client library for ROS1. It looks like the `foxy` branch for that repo isn't fully complete. You'll have to make those changes yourself.

Comment: you are right, I downgraded to ROS1 now

Answer (score 0):

The `ModuleNotFoundError` is thrown by `python interpreter`. You can use `pip install roslibpy` to install roslib module in python. This might solve your `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: I tried it but it remains the same.

Comment: `roslib` isn't provided as a pip package. If you have to install it should be done via `apt`. This is also only true for ROS1, not ROS2.

Comment: Then in this case you can install the module using sudo apt-get install python-roslib and set path in environment variable using export command.

Comment: @HarshDobariya this question is asking about ROS2. `roslib` is strictly a ROS1 package and not used by ROS2.